# TypeError: swaplevel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i am kind of new to pandas,
i am using `unstack` and `swaplevel` to pivot my dataframe and i am getting this error :

> TypeError: swaplevel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

i have checked the pandas doc and the fucntion does take axis as argument, what am i doing wrong please !
thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swaplevel(i=- 2, j=- 1, axis=0)` does have an axis argument, i may have to see your code to be able to trace your error.

On the other-hand, maybe you should try to use swaplevel for each axis individually.
for example :

```
In [1]:

df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})

Out[1]:



   a  b
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  5
3  B  5
4  B  4
5  C  6

df.swaplevel(0)

df.swaplevel(1)
```